# SQL WHERE is anything

Tags: sql, search, where-clause

I'm working on a database query via a search bar and would like it to sometimes yield all results (depending on what is inputted)

I know that for `SELECT` you can use `*` in order to select all columns. Is there similar SQL syntax: i.e. `WHERE name IS *` to essentially always be true?

Edit to clarify:

The nature of the clause is that a variable is used to set the name (I'm actually not able to change the clause, that was made clear). i.e. `WHERE name IS [[inputName]]` (inputName is the decided by the search bar)

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  As written, this is a little difficult to understand...

Comment: Just remove where clause :)

Comment: If can't remove clause, then something like `1=1`?

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE ISNULL(name, '') = ISNULL(name, '')
```

(assuming that 'name' is of a string type)

Just make the column reference itself. However, if this is the only goal of your query, why are you against omitting the WHERE clause?

Comment: This will fail on nulls

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return all results in a SQL statement, you can simply omit the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT <* or field names> FROM <table>;
```

You should use `WHERE` only when you want to filter your data on a certain field. In your case you just don't want to filter at all.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need `WHERE` clause at all in this situation. But if you insist then you should write your predicate so it always returns true. This can be done many ways:

Any predicate like:

```
WHERE 1=1
```

With column:

```
WHERE name = name OR name is null
```

With `LIKE`:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%' OR name is null
```

With passed parameter:

```
WHERE name = @name OR @name is null
```

You can think of more of course. But I think you need the last one. Pass `NULL` from app layer if you want all rows.